# Angular route parameters contraints

Tags: angularjs, routes, constraints

I'm coming from the Asp.net MVC world where route constraints are really useful. I'm currently developing an Angular JS SPA that incorporates client side routing.

I would also like to add parameter constraints to my client-side routes as in:

```
$.routeProvider.when("/post/:id/:name?")
```

where I'd like to constrain my `:id` parameter to only be valid when these are numbers.

I haven't found anything similar in Angular Docs (which are horrible to say the least). Can it be done? And maybe also parameter defaults?

Comment: Horrible ? What version of the docs are you looking at ? They used to be worse than horrible, but I find them pretty decent at the moment.

Comment: @ExpertSystem: Latest docs. They seem fine at the first glance, but when you start having issues you find them incomplete missing info on stuff that usually bothers you.

Comment: I never take a second glance, because I always find what I am looking for with the first :D Seriously, I am not that experienced in Angular, but I never found something missing from the docs (1.2.7+) so far.

Comment: @ExpertSystem: For instance. It doesn't say anywhere (or at least I don't understand it that way) that providing some `$routeProvider.resolve` object would result in controller constructor parameter (as can be seen in @Martin's answer). That's extremely useful info and it isn't really simple to get from the documentation.

Comment: @RobertKoritnok: I don't know - it was pretty obvious at first glance for me: In the documentation on **[`$routeProviders.when()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider#methods_when_parameters)**, it says about the `resolve` property of the `route` object: _" An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. [...]  If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected [...] The map object is: \* `key – {string}:` a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller."_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no built-in way to set route constraints, but you can do it pretty easily yourself by using the resolve feature.

```
module.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/post/:id/:name', {
        controller: 'PostCtrl',
        resolve: {
            id: function ($q, $route) {
                var deferred = $q.defer(),
                    id = parseInt($route.current.params.id, 10);

                if (!isNaN(id)) {
                    deferred.resolve(id);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject('Id is not a number');
                }

                return deferred.promise;
            },
            // This isn't really needed, you can extract the name using 
            // $routeParams.name as you usually would in the controller.
            name: function ($route) {
                return $route.current.params.name;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

By doing it this way you can inject `id` and `name` into `PostCtrl`:

```
module.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, id, name) {

});
```

`id` in this case will be a number. You can of course also use `$routeParams.id` and `$routeParams.name` but those are always strings.

In case something else than a number is passed, then the promise is rejected and you need to handle that, usually in the 'MainCtrl' or 'AppCtrl' if you're doing a SPA.

```
module.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (ev, current, previous, rejection) {
        $log.error('Error changing route: ' + rejection);
        // Will print: Error changing route: Id is not a number
    });
});
```

**Update**

You can use resolve in combination with the `$routeChangeError` event to validate the route and redirect on error. The resolve properties are always run, even if they aren't injected in the controller.

```
resolve: {
    validation: function ($q, $route) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            id = parseInt($route.current.params.id, 10);

        if (!isNaN(id)) {
            deferred.resolve();
        } else {
            deferred.reject('VALIDATION FAILED');
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

In your home controller simply add:

```
module.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (ev, current, previous, rejection) {
        if (rejection === 'VALIDATION FAILED') {
            $location.path('/home');
        }
    });
});
```

This is a quite hacky way to solve it and you might be better of using ui-router (I haven't tried that one). Unfortunately it's not possible to listen to `$routeChangeStart` and abort if needed. Otherwise this could've been solved a lot nicer.

Comment: Would it be possible to make somewhat redirect to "home" in erroneous route parameter?

Comment: BTW: Could `resolve` be used for lazy controller code loading? Is it done in this way or is there any better alternative that people use? Because of resolve returns a promise, it may as well be an Ajax request (or RequireJS modules)

Comment: Lazy controller loading is something that I've seen being discussed, but nothing that I've seen a good implementation for. You could use resolve + `$on` to redirect to "home". I'll update the answer.

Comment: Great! But you can go with simpler resolve: 
`var id = parseInt($route.current.params.id, 10);
return !isNaN(id) ? id : $q.reject();`

Answer (score 5):

### Angular route source change - most transparent constraints

There's a [pull request in AngularJS source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5923/files) (made by me) that adds regular expression constraints to route parameters. It works a simple as providing this kind of route definition:

```
/:parameter:regularexpression
```

An example would be

```
/profile/:id:[1-9]\\d*/edit
```

This means that `id` has to be a number not starting with a 0.

### Additional requirements

There are of course some additional requirements to these parameters:

1. parameter can't be optional or greedy - if it ends with `?` or `*` this character will become part of regular expression (as these are both regular expression tokens with their respective meaning
2. regular expression constraint can't use regular expression capture groups as `(` and `)` get escaped as part of regular expression constraint - this already works this way so if your parameter name includes `(` or `)` they will both be escaped
3. regular expression constraint can't include `/` as these are route segment delimiters

Comment: @BuhBuh yes well, what can I do... Nothing really. This has been pull-requested more than a year ago now...

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), which allows to specify url using regex.

Comment: Still in beta, isn't it?