# Angular JS route param constrain when routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi consider my routing is like below

```
when('/:UserType/:LocationID', {
            title: 'Search',
            templateUrl: function(Param){
                switch (Number(Param.UserType)) {
                    case 2:
                        return 'app/Views/Search/tutor-search.html';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        return 'app/Views/Search/institute-search.html';
                        break;    
                }
            }
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

The above has two route parameters /:UserType/:LocationID  should route only when with the params are numbers , it should not allow the route if it comes with alphabets , i have no idea about doing this , any help would be appreciable.

Comment: This question will Help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205937/angular-route-parameters-contraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ui router you can use url matcher:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher
Like

`'/user/{id:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}}'`

I am not sure about the inbuild angular router. If not than you can add the check in the route change event to prohibit the router.

`$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) { 
   .. and the check
   if (stop) event.preventDefault();
 });`

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [UI-Router framework](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing) ? It offers `Regex Parameters`. Something like:

```
title: 'Search',
// user id of at least one number, location of 2 to 8 numbers
url: '{user:[0-9]{1,*}}/{loc:[0-9]{2,8}}'
```

Comment: Thats UI router, he is using basic angular router

Comment: My bad. Edited the answer. But switching to UI-Router might be a good alternative. There is also this gist which provide regexp support to the regular Angular `$routeProvider`: https://gist.github.com/vladimir-ivanov/6021821

Comment: Its my mistake to use normal routing